# Using Angular 1 libraries in Angular 2?

Tags: angularjs, angular, upgrade

Can I use Angular libraries, for example angular-cookies in Angular 2 app?
Seems that this is not possible, but I want to know this cause I'm planning to upgrade project to Angular2

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In general, no. If you're interested in following the [migration guide](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/upgrade.html) by running Angular 1 and 2 simultaneously, you may be able to get an Angular 1 library functioning, but it's likely not worth your trouble.

I'd encourage you not to be scared of rewriting common libraries for yourself. You'll be surprised by how easy it is - in many instances you'd spend more time trying to figure out a library's documentation, and you gain an intimate understanding of the code.

Comment: Yes, actually I'm looking into approach with rewriting of libraries. But there are a lot of, really. Thanks for your answer!