# Using angular 1 module in angular 2 app

Tags: angularjs, angular, libraries

I want to use an angular 1 module (angular-smart-table) in my angular 2 app and other angular 1 modules. Is there a way to do this?

The docs show how to upgrade an angular 1 app to angular 2. Would all of my external libraries break?

Comment: I'm highly interested in an answer to whether this is even possible or not. Documentation only show how to upgrade angular1 component directives / services, not entire modules which use multiple controllers, services, directives & filters themselves.

Comment: So was I, it seems not to be possible according to this answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35436914/using-angular-1-libraries-in-angular-2