# Using angular 1 and angular 2 simultaneously

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular

I'm new in angular and this is the first experience.

My final goal is to use the following component in angular 2
http://mb21.github.io/JSONedit/

I know a some javascript and I've trying to use a Angular 1 library in an Angular 2 project.

By my search I have found this topic:
[Using Angular 1 libraries in Angular 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35436914/using-angular-1-libraries-in-angular-2)

But as the answer states "In general, no" I'm assuming it is possible to use some components of angular 1 in angular 2. So I am trying to make the following code to run in angular 2 as a test:

**Translation-module.component.html**

```
<select ng-model="selectedName" ng-options="x for x in names">
        <option>teste</option>
</select>


<script>
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
    app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
        $scope.names = ["Emil", "Tobias", "Linus"];
    });
</script>
```

**translation-module.component.ts**

```
import { CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA , Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { angular } from 'angular';

ngAfterViewChecked() {

     // $("#content").load("http://www.google.com");
     var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

     app.controller('myCtrl', function() {
         this.names = ["Emil", "Tobias", "Linus"];
     });
}
```

But this doesn't seems to be working. I'm importing both .js from angular1  and angular 2. Can someone explain me why this isnt working?

thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

The Angular development team have thought about this same question and have introduced the upgrade module as a way to help seamlessly upgrade your application.You can refer to these link:-
https://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/handout/migrate/ng-upgrade/
https://angular.io/guide/upgrade

If you have any particular question about ng-upgrade, please ask.